# How to update a field with dynamic value that involves the current value of the field - using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I have some records in mysql db that have a field by the name "num". Each record have an individual num value.

I what to add a value to each num field.

This simple query `"UPDATE tbl SET num = num+22"` works just fine in phpMyAdmin.

BUT I need to write it in code and I'm using PDO. (it must be PDO).

So I wrote this code:

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE tbl SET num = num + ?");

$sth->bindValue(1, 22, PDO::PARAM_INT);

$sth->execute();
```

After run I got bad result - all num field got the same value in all records

What should I do ?

How can I make the =num field dynamic ?

Comment: you're doing it all right. if you got the same values in all records, then you had all the same values before update.

Comment: you almost right ! the pdo implementation is OK, and I do have different values before the update, BUT I did'nt handle properly null case of the interval (22 which is a calculated figer). Thank you !
Should I delete this question from here ???